# Issue with SetInteval

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Insert function to insert data on the database. The function is called by a button(working properly) and also by a countdown that calls the function when It turns into 0. On this second case the function is inserting the data empty.

Below is my code:

Insert function:

```
$scope.EnviarRespuestas = function () {
        $http.post(
            "insert.php", {
                'preg1': $scope.pregunta1,
                'preg2': $scope.pregunta2,
                'preg3': $scope.pregunta3,
                'preg4': $scope.pregunta4,
                'preg5': $scope.pregunta5,
                'preg6': $scope.pregunta6,
                'preg7': $scope.pregunta7,
                'preg8': $scope.pregunta8,
                'preg9': $scope.pregunta9,
                'preg10': $scope.pregunta10,
                'dni': $scope.dniaux,
                'apNom': $scope.nombreaux,
                'tiempo': $scope.tiempo
            }

        ).then(function (data) {
            console.log($scope.pregunta1);
            $scope.pregunta1 = "";
            $scope.pregunta2 = "";
            $scope.pregunta3 = "";
            $scope.pregunta4 = "";
            $scope.pregunta5 = "";
            $scope.pregunta6 = "";
            $scope.pregunta7 = "";
            $scope.pregunta8 = "";
            $scope.pregunta9 = "";
            $scope.pregunta10 = "";
            $scope.apNom = "";
            $scope.dni = "";
            $scope.tiempo = "";
            clearInterval(timer);
            $('.button').removeClass('blue');
            $('.ui.menu').find('.item').tab('change tab', 1);
        });
}
```

and Here's the function that calls the first one when the countdown is 0:

```
$scope.startTimer = function () {
    $scope.segundos = 15;
    $scope.minutos = 00;
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        $scope.segundos--;
        if ($scope.segundos < 10) {
            $scope.segundos = "0" + $scope.segundos
        }
        if ($scope.minutos == 0 && $scope.segundos == 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            $scope.calcularTiempo();
            $scope.EnviarRespuestas();
        }
        $scope.$apply();
        if ($scope.segundos <= 0) {
            $scope.minutos--;
            $scope.segundos = 05;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: What does $scope.calcularTiempo(); this function do?

Comment: I haven't used angular for a while, but shouldn't you move all the code in the the `setInterval` callback  (because it is a non angular asnyc function)  into a `$scope.$apply(function() { // the code });` block, because otherwise the values in `$scope` might not be synced. And because you call `$scope.$apply();` is after your `$scope.EnviarRespuestas();` the `$scope.pregunta1` values are not set?

Comment: That function just calculates the time that took to complete a form

Comment: Hi Niese, yes, the problem is that when the function is activated by the timeout the values on variables $scope.pregunta1 and etc are undefined

Answer (score 1):

Well the entire `$scope.startTimer` function seems unnecessary as angularjs already has a `$timeout` function which can serve the same purpose;

```
$timeout(function()  {
  // what to call
}, 15000) // 15000 = 15 seconds
```

Secondly if you already have a button that works you can just call `.click()` on it when the timer expires.

```
$timeout(function()  {
  angular.element('#buttonId').click();
}, 15000) // 15000 = 15 seconds
```

Comment: Hi Chukwuemeka,

The getelementbyid worked for me. Thanks so much for taking the time to help me. Thanks also the other ones that comented